# Как работать с SetWindowPos() на Си?

Tags: c, winapi

Если в обработчике `WM_CREATE` вызываю

```
SetWindowPos(HwndGlavOkna, HWND_TOP, 500, 500, 500, 500, SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
```

то окно отображается в соответствии с параметрами функции. Но если в обработчике я вызываю написанную мной функцию, которая находится в `main.c`

```
void SetWinPos(void) {
    SetWindowPos(HwndGlavOkna, HWND_TOP, 500, 500, 500, 500, SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
    return;
}
```

то окно выводится прямоугольным в левом верхнем углу. Почему? Вообще мне надо вызывать функцию из другого файла, в которой `SetWindowPos`.

Comment: Что такое `HwndGlavOkna` и откуда оно берется в обоих случаях?

Comment: Это глобальная переменная, берётся в обоих случаях из одного места. `HwndGlavOkna  =  CreateWindowEx ()`.

Comment: Ну это значит, что либо у вас происходит "волшебство и мистика", либо вы что-то выдумываете (напр. `HwndGlavOkna` - никакая не глобальная переменная). Показывайте реальный код, а не рассказы о нем.

Comment: Всё, разобрался. У меня была глобальная и локальная переменная с одним именем `HwndGlavOkna`, поэтому возникала ошибка.